# Delete Result Rows from a Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables named `BM_Data1` & `BM_Data1_May62019`. Both Tables contains the same data as `BM_Data1_May62019` is the copy of `BM_Data1` table. But `BM_Data1` has some extra rows, How can I delete those extra rows from `BM_Data1` and make it same like `BM_Data1_May62019`.

I got the extra rows using the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM BM_DATA1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM BM_DATA1_MAY62019) a
```

There are **7803** extra rows, how can I delete them from `BM_Data1` table?

*Thank You*

Comment: What identifying columns do you have in these tables?

Comment: is there any relation between these tables?

Comment: There is no relation between these tables, ```BM_DATA1_MAY62019``` is an old backup of ```BM_DATA1```

Comment: But you must have something that identify each row? Like an ID or something other unique?

Comment: It means you have same Primary Key values in both tables right? or you don't have pk too?

Comment: Actually I am not sure if any column contains UNIQUE Data, otherwise it will be easy for me to delete using simple delete query

Comment: Should I need to create an additional column with auto increment in ```BM_DATA1``` first?

Comment: Any table should have a PK, something unique you can identify that specific row with. If you have matching IDs in both tables, you can use a `MERGE` statement to delete it.

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: @Qirel I found it, in both tables Column ```RECID``` containing unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed RECID is common in both table with unique value, you can try this following script

```
DELETE FROM BM_DATA1
WHERE RECID NOT IN
(
    SELECT RECID FROM BM_DATA1_MAY62019
)
```

Comment: it deleted only 613 records instead of 7803

Comment: That means other RECID are common between two table.

Comment: which means table BM_DATA1 has multiple entries with the same RECID as BM_DATA1_MAY62019

Comment: you should use other column with unique column, may be time log if you have in your data set

Comment: After using above query now both table has same number of rows i.e **255276**
but when I execute ```EXCEPT``` for these tables it still shows **7190** Rows. I wonder why?

Comment: That means there are difference in data in other columns with same RECID. EXCEPT consider combination of data from all columns.

Answer (score 0):

use just delete with a correlated subquery

```
   delete from [BM_DATA1] 
   where not exists 
     (select 1 
    from [BM_DATA1_MAY62019]
    where [BM_DATA1_MAY62019].RECID = [BM_DATA1].RECID -- put here here identified column name
     )
```

Comment: Using this generates the following error  **Invalid Object Name**
Also It is not clear in this query that from which table it has to delete the rows

Comment: I got this error by using that query ```Cannot update the view or function 'cte' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement with `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE`.

`MERGE` works like a `JOIN` of sorts, and you need to be able to identify which rows are equal. You do this by the `ON` clause - for you, that would be `RECID`.

I suggest you run these in a transaction first, so you verify that you only delete the data you intend to - and commit the transaction only when you are sure you have the right configuration. If something is wrong, you can rollback

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION

MERGE BM_DATA1 AS Target
USING BM_DATA1_MAY62019as Source 
   ON (Target.RECID = Source.RECID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
   THEN DELETE;

SELECT * FROM BM_DATA1

-- ROLLBACK TRANSACTION -- Uncomment and use this if it deleted the wrong data
-- COMMIT -- Uncomment and use this if it deleted the right data!
```

Comment: it deleted only 613 records instead of 7803

Answer (score 0):

I've included some DDL so you can run this for yourself to help you understand the example. The ID column is the one that is common to both tables and you are removing the rows in A that are not in B

```
create table #data_a( id int, val int)
create table #data_b( id int, val int)

insert into #data_a select 1, 1 
insert into #data_a select 2, 4 
insert into #data_a select 3, 5 
insert into #data_a select 4, 5 
insert into #data_a select 5, 5 
insert into #data_a select 6, 5 
insert into #data_a select 7, 5 
insert into #data_a select 8, 5 

insert into #data_b select 1, 1 
insert into #data_b select 2, 4 
insert into #data_b select 3, 5 
insert into #data_b select 4, 5 
insert into #data_b select 5, 5 

-- delete the extra rows in A 
delete a from #data_a as a
left join #data_b as b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null

-- we can see the rows are no longer in B
select * from #data_a
select * from #data_b

drop table #data_a
drop table #data_b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t1(id int, demo int);
create table t2(id int, demo int);

insert into t1 values (1, 1);
insert into t2 values (1, 1);

insert into t1 values (2, 2);
insert into t2 values (2, 2);

insert into t1 values (3, 3);
insert into t2 values (3, 3);

insert into t1 values (4, 4); -- t1 table has some extra rows
insert into t1 values (5, 5); -- t1 table has some extra rows
insert into t1 values (6, 6); -- t1 table has some extra rows
```

To delete those records from first table which are not second table:

```
delete from t1 where id not in (select id from t2)
```